# application not registered on db instance and no application

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I'm running python within a ubuntu vagrant box

I keep getting this error whenever i run **runserver** or **syncdb**.

> application not registered on db instance and no application

Full stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 41, in <module>
    models.PSABase.metadata.create_all(db.engine)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 922, in engine
    return self.get_engine()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 931, in get_engine
    app = self.get_app(app)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 957, in get_app
    'application not registered on db instance and no application' RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no applicationbound to current context
```

the error occurs in manage.py:

```
@manager.command
def syncdb():
    User.metadata.create_all(db.engine)

manager.add_command('server', Server(host='192.168.33.15'))
manager.add_command('shell', Shell(make_context=_make_context))

from pixelpin_auth_flask_sqlalchemy import models
models.PSABase.metadata.create_all(db.engine)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.add_command("runserver", Server(
    use_debugger = True,
    use_reloader = True,
    host = '192.168.33.15'))
    manager.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

i put:

```
from pixelpin_auth_flask_sqlalchemy import models
models.PSABase.metadata.create_all(db.engine)
```

in the wrong place it should be in:

```
@manager.command
def syncdb():
    User.metadata.create_all(db.engine)
    from pixelpin_auth_flask_sqlalchemy import models
    models.PSABase.metadata.create_all(db.engine)

manager.add_command('server', Server(host='192.168.33.16'))
manager.add_command('shell', Shell(make_context=_make_context))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.add_command("runserver", Server(
    use_debugger = True,
    use_reloader = True,
    host = '192.168.33.16'))
    manager.run()
```